# Is it possible to modify browsers Date object?

Tags: javascript, timestamp

Is it safe to use the Date.now() object to store timestamps?
Or is it possible for a user/person to modify the Date object in browser console and change the behavior of the Date.now()?

Answer (score 2):

Possible? Yes:

```
console.log(Date.now());

var Date = {
    now: function(){
        return "It's too late";
    }
};

console.log(Date.now());
```

```
1479290688311
It's too late
```

Safe? I've tried in Stack Overflow and it's already throwing a good bunch of JavaScript errors—I couldn't even submit the answer, I had to reload the site. But you can't prevent a determined user from breaking his own browser. And if you're talking about data security, you simply cannot trust external input of any kind.

Comment: Great example @Álvaro-González

Comment: `Date.now =  function(){
   return "I have been replaced";
}` is even simpler

Comment: @mplungjan That's right. You can wipe out the whole object or just bits of it.

Answer (score 0):

The [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) will contain the date of the computer the browser runs on. It is not magically knowing that the user changed the date. If they allow the location API to run, you may be able to double check.

The Date methods are not read-only so you can override them:

This is simpler than Álvaro González suggested and does not give any errors in Chrome

```js
Date.now =  function(){
   return "I have been replaced";
}
console.log(Date.now());
```